# Отправка данных из формы, в чём ошибка?

Tags: php, html, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Подать заявку на участие в акции</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sel1">Регион:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1" name="region">
                            <option>Алтайский край</option>
                            <option>Амурская область</option>
                            <option>Архангельская область</option>
                            <option>Белгородская область</option>
                            <option>Брянская область</option>
                            <option>Владимирская область</option>
                            <option>Волгоградская область</option>
                            <option>Вологодская область</option>
                            <option>Воронежская область</option>
                            <option>г.Москва</option>
                            <option>Еврейская автономная область</option>
                            <option>Забайкальский край</option>
                            <option>Ивановская область</option>
                            <option>Байконур</option>
                            <option>Иркутская область</option>
                            <option>Кабардино-Балкарская Республика</option>
                            <option>Калининградская область</option>
                            <option>Калужская область</option>
                            <option>Камчатский край</option>
                            <option>Карачаево-Черкесская Республика</option>
                            <option>Кемеровская область</option>
                            <option>Кировская область</option>
                            <option>Костромская область</option>
                            <option>Краснодарский край</option>
                            <option>Красноярский край</option>
                            <option>Курганская область</option>
                            <option>Курская область</option>
                            <option>Ленинградская область</option>
                            <option>Липецкая область</option>
                            <option>Магаданская область</option>
                            <option>Московская область</option>
                            <option>Мурманская область</option>
                            <option>Ненецкий автономный округ</option>
                            <option>Нижегородская область</option>
                            <option>Новгородская область</option>
                            <option>Омская область</option>
                            <option>Оренбургская область</option>
                            <option>Орловская область</option>
                            <option>Пензенская область</option>
                            <option>Пермский край</option>
                            <option>Приморский край</option>
                            <option>Псковская область</option>
                            <option>Республика Адыгея (Адыгея)</option>
                            <option>Республика Алтай</option>
                            <option>Республика Башкортостан</option>
                            <option>Республика Бурятия</option>
                            <option>Республика Дагестан</option>
                            <option>Республика Ингушетия</option>
                            <option>Республика Калмыкия</option>
                            <option>Республика Карелия</option>
                            <option>Республика Коми</option>
                            <option>Республика Крым</option>
                            <option>Республика Марий Эл</option>
                            <option>Республика Мордовия</option>
                            <option>Республика Саха (Якутия)</option>
                            <option>Республика Северная Осетия - Алания</option>
                            <option>Республика Татарстан (Татарстан)</option>
                            <option>Республика Тыва</option>
                            <option>Республика Хакасия</option>
                            <option>Ростовская область</option>
                            <option>Рязанская область</option>
                            <option>Самарская область</option>
                            <option>Санкт-Петербург</option>
                            <option>Саратовская область</option>
                            <option>Сахалинская область</option>
                            <option>Свердловская область</option>
                            <option>Севастополь</option>
                            <option>Смоленская область</option>
                            <option>Ставропольский край</option>
                            <option>Тамбовская область</option>
                            <option>Тверская область</option>
                            <option>Томская область</option>
                            <option>Тульская область</option>
                            <option>Тюменская область</option>
                            <option>Удмуртская Республика</option>
                            <option>Ульяновская область</option>
                            <option>Хабаровский край</option>
                            <option>Ханты-Мансийский автономный округ - Югра</option>
                            <option>Челябинская область</option>
                            <option>Чеченская Республика</option>
                            <option>Чувашская Республика - Чувашия</option>
                            <option>Чукотский автономный округ</option>
                            <option>Ямало-Ненецкий автономный округ</option>
                            <option>Ярославская область</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <input class="modalinput" placeholder="Наименование учреждения" type="text" name="uchname">
                    <input class="modalinput" placeholder="Адрес учреждения" type="text" name="adress">
                    <input class="modalinput" placeholder="ФИО конкурсанта" type="text" name="fio">
                    <input class="modalinput" placeholder="Название работы" type="text" name="wname">
                    <input class="modalinput" placeholder="Электронная почта" type="text" name="email">
                    <textarea maxlength="300" placeholder="Комментарий" name="comment"></textarea>
                    <input type="file" accept="application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,
    text/plain, application/pdf, image/*">
                    <p>Разрешенные расширения:<br>.doc, .txt, .jpg, .png, .gif и др.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Данные не отправляются, соединение с БД проходит, где моя ошибка?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данные не отправляются? Или в базу не пишутся? Для начала нужно это понять.

Comment: Посмотрите что в переменных в вашем скрипте

Comment: @Suvitruf, не записываются в базу

Comment: @Pavel, а что с ними не так, указаны переменные и заданы имена input'ов?

Comment: Вывод `mysqli_error` покажите.

Comment: @Suvitruf прошу прощения, как? :D

Comment: @user234223 `die(mysqli_error($db));` после вызова `mysql_query`.

Comment: @Suvitruf https://imgur.com/a/LJJQf

Comment: @Suvitruf, голубчик, тут устаревшая PHP, никаких mysql i пожалуйста xD и уж тем более $this->db в функциональном подходе

Comment: @ScreamingVoices оу :C

Answer (score 2):

[`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-select-db.php) выбирает базу данных, а не её тип. на скриншоте в PhpMyAdmin у вас указано название Базы данных `meowwiif_gos`, такое и подставьте в ранее упомянутую функцию.

Также проверьте наличие `PRIMARY` ключа с `AUTO_INCREMENT` у поля `id`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/l81Y9

Всё равно не записывает.

Comment: @user234223 будьте так добры добавьте проверку на ошибку как в Примере#1 http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php и пришлите ответ сервера

Comment: Ошибка была в том, что пароль от базы данных не применился, спасибо! :)